# Generating: $\frac{1}{2\ln2}-\frac{1}{3\ln3}+\frac{1}{4\ln4}...$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Help the King out. Brand new stuff to him. I know (-1)^n has something do to with it but I don't know what else.

Write in sigma notation:

$\frac{1}{2\ln2}-\frac{1}{3\ln3}+\frac{1}{4\ln4}...$

Comment: Why all this hate for the Squirrel King? Maybe because he hasnt shown an attempt, and tried to bribe us. Bribery doesnt work when we dont do it for the points, we do it for knowledge, and practice.

Comment: King Squirrel you might be, King Google not so much, otherwise your most devoted [servant](http://www.google.com) surely would have been able to provide you with [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series)

Comment: Usually people try a bunch of stuff in their head. I can't figure it out though.

Comment: @fgp He's looking for the sum of the series. Anywho, WA gives $\approx 0.526412$

Comment: @KingSquirrel Your question was closed but I think it's a good one.  Please consider editing it to include context (your own thoughts, etc.) and I will vote to reopen it.

Comment: The King will let you feel his wrath if you do not reopen the question.

Comment: Ok now it's clear what I am asking, vote to reopen.

Comment: Wait, are you trying to write the sum in *sigma* notation, or trying to compute the sum itself?

Comment: Sigma notation great sir.

Comment: $\sum_{k=2}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{1}{k\log k}$.

Comment: [ISC](http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/standard) yields 'tentatively' $\large{1 \over 2} + {\sqrt{12\sqrt{3} + 42} \over 300}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with $1$ minus the [Dirichlet eta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function) :
$$1- \eta(s)=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^s}=\frac 1{2^s}-\frac 1{3^s}+\cdots$$
Since $\,\displaystyle \int \frac 1{n^s} ds=-\frac 1{n^s\log(n)}\;$ we deduce  $\,\displaystyle \frac 1{n\log(n)}=\int_1^\infty \frac 1{n^s} ds\;$ and :

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n\,\log(n)}=\sum_{n=2}^\infty(-1)^n\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{n^s}\,ds=\int_1^\infty 1-\eta(s)\; ds$$

You may rewrite $\eta(s)$ as $\,\eta(s)=\left(1-2^{1-s}\right)\zeta(s)\,$ but this shouldn't make the last integral much easier. I don't know a closed form for this last integral (integrals over $\zeta$ don't usually give closed forms as opposed to the corresponding series).

Hoping this helped anyway,

Comment: If I have one that works but where n has to be zero to kick it off is it ok?

Comment: @KingSquirrel: you'll be in trouble for $n=1$ because of $\dfrac 1{\log(1)}$ and at $n=0$ because of $\dfrac 10\;$!

Comment: @KingSquirrel: of course you may write your sum as $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+2)\,\log(n+2)}=\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k\,\log(k)}$$ if that's the point! (sorry I was concerned by the result previously...)

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I got. Ok thanks.

Comment: Glad it helped @KingSquirrel Fine continuation!